# Iterate over something that may be an iterator or a single element

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following function:

```
def sum(summands)
    s = 0
    for a in summands:
        s = a + s
```

The user might call it with a list `sum([1, 2, 3])` but it would be convenient if you could also call it directly with a number `sum(5)`. (It's not actually about numbers, just a simplified example.)

I could invent a function:

```
def make_iterable(x):
    # returns x if x is iterable, returns [x] if x is not iterable
```

**But is there an even shorter, built-in way to make a single element iterable?**

Comment: `try` to iterate over it and fallback to single-element behaviour otherwise?

Comment: "Is there an even shorter, builtin way to make a single element iterable" -- Sure ... `iterable = [not_iterable]` ... I think that the bigger problem is that you seem to want to treat iterables and non-iterables the same.  I feel like you're taking duck typing _too_ far.  You should always know whether the object you have is iterable or not.  If it isn't iterable, but you want to pass it to a function that requires an iterable, then you should just make it into an iterable when you pass it to the function --- `func_requiring_iterable([not_iterable])`

Comment: The `make_iterable(x)` solution is already shorter than that... ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: Then I have a problem in the case where it is actually iterable.

Comment: @Michael -- I edited my comment further.  I think that the main problem is that you want to treat iterables and not iterables on equal terms when they aren't.  You should know concretely at all times whether the object you're working with is iterable or not.  If you don't know that, then your probably writing code that is too generic to be easily read/understood and is likely _less_ useful that way.  At least, that's my 2c ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's all you need

```py
def sum(summands):
    s = 0
    summands = summands if isinstance(summands, list) else [summands]
    for a in summands:
        s = a + s
    return s
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this.

```
def sum(summands)
    s = 0

    try:
        iter(summands)
    except TypeError:
        return summands

    for a in summands:
        s = a + s
    return s
```

Or, if you wanted to use the shell function that you proposed, you can pull out that `try:` `except:` into `make_iterable`

Python 2.x:

```
def make_iterable(x):
    try:
        iter(x)
    except TypeError:
        x=[x]
    return x
```

Python 3.x:

```
def make_iterable(x):
    try: yield from x
    except TypeError: yield x
```

And then call it in sum

```
def sum(summands)
    s = 0

    summands = make_iterable(summands)

    for a in summands:
        s = a + s
    return s
```

Comment: I would wrap with try/except only `it = iter(summands)` to prevent unnecessary error swallowing.

Comment: Or in 3.x - `try: yield from something` and `except TypeError: yield something` then use that as your `make_iterable`

Comment: @JonClements I like the use of `yield`. I have not used it before, but it would help achieve a shorter result as the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You could check inside the function whether it is iterable or not and wrap it in a list if it is not. I believe that collections.Iterable is a good way to do this:

```
import collections

if isinstance(summands, collections.Iterable):
    tmp = summands
else:
    tmp = [summands]
```

Comment: a string is an iterable too so may not be %100 secure to check if object is `collections.Iterable` type.

Comment: @ozgur -- Not sure what you're saying here.  `isinstance('abc', collections.Iterable)` returns `True`.  Since OP didn't distinguish between strings and other types of iterables, I would assume that this is the proper behavior...

Comment: This is the better answer IMO except you're overriding the iter built-in

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit I didn't mean to literally use that variable name, but I editted it to be clearer. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it's iterable and make it one (assuming it's not a string). Note: `sum` is the name of a built-in, so you probably shouldn't name your own function the same thing. See [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
import collections

def mysum(summand):
    if not isinstance(summand, collections.Iterable):
        summand = (summand,)
    elif isinstance(summand, str):
        raise TypeError('string argument not supported')
    s = 0
    for a in summand:
        s += a
    return s

print(mysum([1, 2, 3]))
print(mysum(42))
print(mysum("won't work"))
```

Output:

```
6
42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iterate-over-something.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(mysum("won't work"))
  File "iterate-over-something.py", line 10, in mysum
    raise TypeError('string argument not supported')
TypeError: string argument not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test if it is a list or an int:

```
if isinstance(summand, list)
    sumlist(summand)
if isinstance(summand, int)
    Sumint(summand)
```

And then write summing functions for each type.  Or you could use a list comp to turn the integer ino a list 'summand = [x for x in range(summand +1)] and use that.

Comment: What about sets, dicts, tuples, or any other custom iteraterable?